# Excel driven Selenium Tests

Tags: excel, selenium, testing, data-driven

Is there any way we can extract Selenium-IDE output as an excel sheet and then use java reflection to trigger them one-by-one?  Any existing good tool already done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post should point you in the right direction?

http://functionaltestautomation.blogspot.com/2009/10/dataprovider-data-driven-testing-with.html

Comment: Tim,

Is it possible to use the same kind of dataprovider in JUnit also... as in our application, we are using JUnit4.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been on here in a while... I have not written data driven tests myself but read about others doing it.. Here is a good link describing how.. to set up data driven tests in junit, that other article was using TestNG as you noticed. But this link does use excel as you specifically noted in your question so maybe just what you are after?
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2009/11/28/data-driven-tests-junit-4-and-excel